# How to center navbar elements vertically (Twitter Bootstrap)?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, less, vertical-alignment

This is my CSS/LESS CSS code so far:

```
//make navbar taller
@navbarHeight: 60px;

//make navbar link text 18px
.navbar-inner {
    font-size: 18px;
}

//make navbar brand text 36px
.navbar .brand {
    font-size: 36px;
}
```

Which produces this:

[image]

*FYI I'm using the Twitter Bootstrap demo code, I haven't altered the html (aside from changing the brand name).*

As you can see, the brand name is centered vertically within the navbar like it should be, but the navigation links are not (they're bit higher towards the top). The problem only became apparent once I altered the height of the navbar. How can I get them to be centred vertically (like [this](http://www.fleetio.com/) website, for example)?

If it's any help, highlighting the elements in Chrome shows this:

[image]

Comment: add your code to http://www.jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `.brand` class uses a different `line-height` than the base text that is used throughout Bootstrap, as well as a few other key differences.

Relevant parts from the original bootstrap navbar LESS -

For `.brand`:

```
.brand {
  // Vertically center the text given $navbarHeight
  @elementHeight: 20px;
  padding: ((@navbarHeight - @elementHeight) / 2 - 2) 20px ((@navbarHeight - @elementHeight) / 2 + 2);
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

For links in the navbar:

```
.navbar .nav > li > a {
  @elementHeight: 20px;
  padding: ((@navbarHeight - @elementHeight) / 2 - 1) 10px ((@navbarHeight - @elementHeight) / 2 + 1);
  line-height: 19px;
}
```

You'll probably need to play around with the values of `@elementHeight`, `line-height`, and maybe `padding` for the `.navbar .nav > li > a` selector to reflect the bigger 60px `@navbarHeight` (these default values are meant for a 40px `@navbarHeight`). Maybe try a 40px `@elementHeight` and/or a 29px line-height to start.

Comment: Thanks. Manipulating the `line-height` of `.navbar .nav > li > a` did the trick (changing `@elementHeight` seemed to have no effect).

Comment: .brand alone doesnt work. Bootstrap's ".nav .brand" overrides it. One has to insert ".nav .brand{ " and following your code, then only it will override bootstrap's original padding.

Comment: I use just line-height, similar to my logo height. It's working good :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

`display: table-cell;`

Answer (score 0):

If the above answer doesn't help, and you haven't touch the html, the only thing I can think of is the css. You might want to look at the css which the bootstrap example used and modify the sizes of `.navbar-inner` and `.navbar .brand` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had a similar issue with Bootstrap 3 but with the brand eliment. In the end I used the following css:

```
.navbar-brand {
  font-size: 3em;
  line-height: 1em;
}
```

My nav bar has increased in size due to a 50px image, with top and bottom margins of 10px. Not sure if that is of any help.