# How to use bootstrap for text in html.erb

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

It can be a pretty stupid question. I stylized menu by using bootstrap, but in my navbar I want to add a text, but when I add text it complitly move up. And what i want to ask is "How can i add bootstrap-sass styling to text?"

This is part of code what I need to style:

```
  <% if user_signed_in? %>
                        <li>Hello, <%= current_user.email %></li>
```

This is bootstrap styling what I've used:

```
<li><%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
```

And screenshot, how it looks:

[image]

Comment: I will tell you that it's not a 'stupid' question - working with the bootstrap navbar I've found is difficult as well.  I'd look into the 'right' option in navbars.  You can have a right and left option.  The example code [here](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar) should help - navbar-right is what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few questions like this already asked and answered:

[How to center navbar elements vertically (Twitter Bootstrap)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408667/how-to-center-navbar-elements-vertically-twitter-bootstrap)

[Bootstrap 3 : Vertically Center Navigation Links when Logo Increasing The Height of Navbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19844561/bootstrap-3-vertically-center-navigation-links-when-logo-increasing-the-height)

I believe your issues stem from inconsistent line-heights combined with vertical-align issues. You may just have to add your own CSS to override the Bootstrap defaults.